# Delete row from child table when a row from parent table gets deleted

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, alter-table, alter

```
   CREATE TABLE LECTURER 
   (LectID      VARCHAR(12)  NOT NULL,      
   Name   VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL, 
  Email     VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL, 
  Faculty    VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL, 
 CONSTRAINT LECTURER_pkey PRIMARY KEY (LectID));


 CREATE TABLE NOK   
(LectID   VARCHAR(12)  NOT NULL,  
 Name       VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,  
 DOB        DATE          NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT NOK_pkey PRIMARY KEY (LectID, Name, DOB),
CONSTRAINT NOK_fkey FOREIGN KEY (LectID) references LECTURER (LectID));
```

I have created 2 table in mysql , How can I make sure, when row from `LECTURER` table gets deleted associated row from `NOK` should also get deleted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` in `NOK` table.

change

```
CONSTRAINT NOK_fkey FOREIGN KEY (LectID) references LECTURER (LectID)
```

to

```
CONSTRAINT NOK_fkey FOREIGN KEY (LectID) references LECTURER (LectID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**Edited ==**

Before executing above script, you need to execute below, so that you won't get any error.

```
ALTER TABLE NOK DROP FOREIGN KEY NOK_fkey;
```

Comment: but i was required to do it using alter table .. so i just alter table ADD CONSTRAINT NOK_fkey FOREIGN KEY (LectID) references LECTURER (LectID)
ON DELETE CASCADE  is it ?

Comment: @sozai if you have created contraint already then, you need to drop it first. And yes, you can do that.

Comment: @sozai ok, did you tried executing the alter script ?

Comment: @sozai So, now you understood, what I meant ?

Comment: @sozai no, You need to drop **ONLY** constraint which you are going to create.

Comment: @sozai OMG. I'm saying need to drop the foreign key only, it's not about SQL, it's logical

Comment: oo so i drop my foreign key  NOK_fkey is it  ?